# App freezes when signing back after logout - firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just added a logout button to my app. First of all, there is no problem at the beginning. When touching the logout button, it works and throws me to the loginviewcontroller. However, when touching the play button after re-signed in, the app just freezes without giving any error. When I restarts the app and the app works without any problem. I have no idea about the issue.

```
if (logoutBtn?.contains(location))!{

            if isEnabled == false {

            } else if isEnabled == true {

                logoutBtn?.color = customColor
                logoutLabel?.fontColor = fontColor

                try! Auth.auth().signOut()
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC")




                Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
                    if user != nil {

                    } else {
                        UIView.transition(with: self.view!, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCurlUp, animations: {

                        }, completion: { completed in
                            self.view?.window?.rootViewController = vc
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you clearing the user?

Comment: That's all I do for log out. Should I do something when implementing logout?

Comment: Have you tried to use breakpoints and see which row the app crashes?

Comment: As I understand, it happens when I logged in back from uiviewcontroller to skscene. At first, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use skscene for login screen. You can find the code below:

**GameViewController:**

```
 func handleFacebookBtn() {
    print("handleFacebookBtn")
    let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to login: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        guard (FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil else {
            print("Failed to get access token")
            return
        }

        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)


        // Perform login by calling Firebase APIs
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(okayAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                return
            }

            // Present the main view
            if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GameViewController") {
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        })

    }
}
func handleGoogleBtn() {
    print("handleTwitterBtn")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        print("Successfull sign in!")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToGame", sender: self)
    }
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}